# How to add a host that is a variable before executing a module in ansible?

Tags: module, ansible, host

This is the task I want to execute

```
- hosts: variable-vm
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - name: Transfer file from local to remote
     copy:
       src: /tmp/file
       dest: /home/ansible/
```

Now before the user executes my playbook I want him to enter

```
--extra-vars "server=variable-vm"
```

In other tasks this was defined at the beginning of the yml file like this:

```
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    my_server: "{{ server }}"
  become: yes
  tasks:
```

and when I needed to I would deligate the task to that variable vm with

```
 delegate_to: '{{ my_server }}'
```

Keep in mind that I have defined the variable-vm inside the inventory under "webservers"

Essentially my machine is connected to dozens of servers with ssh keys and the servers are defined under /etc/hosts. All I want from the user is to enter the name of the server that is defined in /etc/hosts and use that variable as an input for "hosts:" before the copy task.

As far as I can see there is no other way to specify the remote machine I want to copy the file to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CzipO2, You can send the host using extra_vars to the ansible-playbook command as shown below,

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml -e new_host=192.168.10.10
```

And can delegate the task to this host.

According to my knowledge, it is not possible to take host in a variable and then run the tasks on it, you can always delegate the task to the host specified using extra_vars.

Comment: Oh yeah, completely forgot about how delegate_to works.